# override responsive styles for printing

Tags: css, printing, sass, media-queries

We are using breakpoints for responsiveness in SASS. Desktop styles start at min-width:960px. Unfortunately, when we PRINT the page, the browser uses the tablet styles - in other words, it 'thinks' printing the page is less than 960px wide. I know how to write print styles to take over, but we simply want to use the desktop styles for printing without having to duplicate them into a media print CSS query.

Is there a way to tell the browser to use the Desktop styles when printing?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@media print {
    //Your CSS
}
```

You can read about @media print and how to use it at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

An example of application could be

```
@media print {
    .header {
        display:none!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not how to do print styles, rather it is how to overcome the fact that print styles fall back to the tablet-size breakpoint styles, then applies print styles on top of that.

OP wants to use have print styles use the desktop breakpoint as the base, then apply print styles on top of that. I'm having the same issues, so I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: I did answer the question. Use the `!important` tag at the end of each line in the print rule.

Comment: hellojason is correct - the question is how to tell print which breakpoint to use, not to write new print styles for the entire site. I think there may be something in pixel density or dpi settings, but to date, I have not been able to get it to work. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fair enough, are you able to provide a live example?